# SFDX: Authorize an Org failed to run in VSCODE

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code, visualstudiocode

**SFDX: Authorize an Org failed to run in VS Code:**

I am tring to authorize an org on visual studio code but when I am trying authorize it, I am getting the below error.

**SFDX: Authorize an Org failed to run**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Verify if salesforce CLI is installed successfully or not .
2. Add the path of the Salesforce CLI to the environmental variables.

Please follow the below article to install and set the path for the Salesforce CLI.

[Salesforce CLI Installation steps](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli.htm)

[steps for setting up VSCODE](https://salesforcediaries.com/2019/02/21/setup-your-developer-environment-for-lightning-web-comp/)